# How to apply for using restricted capability for UWP Store App

Tags: uwp

According to MS documentation: 
"Restricted capabilities, which require approval for Microsoft Store submission and/or are generally only available to Microsoft and certain partners."

How to proceed with this approval process.

We have one company account with Microsoft (this one is also partner account)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations#restricted-capabilities), you will have to justify why you need this restricted capabilities during the submission process.

> Previously, we required you to contact support to get approval to use
> a capability. We now allow you to provide this info in Partner Center
> as part of the submission process.
>
> When you upload packages for your submission, we will detect whether
> any restricted capabilities are declared. If we do so, you will be
> required to provide details about how your product uses each
> capability on the Submission options page. Be sure to provide as much
> detail as possible to help us understand why your product needs to
> declare the capability. Note that this may add some additional time
> for your submission to complete the certification process.

Comment: thanks. I think this information is enough for me. :)